# Unity URP Can't override virtual function

Tags: unity-game-engine, overriding

I'm trying to follow this article: https://bronsonzgeb.com/index.php/2021/03/20/pseudo-metaballs-with-scriptable-renderer-features-in-unitys-urp/

I've gotten to the end of it and tried to compile but got the following message:

```
RenderWater.cs(38,30): error CS0115: 'RenderWater.RenderObjectsPass.OnCameraSetup(CommandBuffer, ref RenderingData)': no suitable method found to override
```

The line in question is:

```
public override void OnCameraSetup(CommandBuffer cmd, ref RenderingData renderingData)
```

I'm new to URP and so I have likely missed something, but I have not idea what

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just need to make sure you have "Universal RP" installed in the Package Manager.

---

Are you inheriting the right class? You need to make sure that you're doing the following instead of inheriting from MonoBehavior.

```
YourClass : TheClassWithThatMethodInIt
```

Are you running into a namespace issue? Does VS flag it as missing the method to override as well?

Comment: This is the class:
class RenderObjectsPass : ScriptableRenderPass

And here is the documentation saying that it should be there:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@9.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderPass.html#methods

Comment: Another thing is that I tried to copy and paste the article code itself, but that ran into the same issue. I'm stuck on what it could be

Comment: At the top of your script do you have the right "using" namespaces? You'll probably need 
using 'UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal';

Comment: I have that as well, I wish I could format it better

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

Comment: Are you using VisualStudio? If you command/ctrl + click on the "ScriptableRenderPass" script so it takes you to that reference, is the virtual method there? If you Debug.Log() in your override method do you see it in the console? Is your script in a strange folder? Do you for sure have Universal RP package installed in the package manager? Do you have URP pipeline set in project settings > Quality and project settings > Graphics?

Comment: It's not there?? I think I may have an old version of it so I'll update my Unity version and hopefully that will solve the issue

Comment: You should be able to install "Universal RP" within the package manager. Up at the top of the package manager there should be a drop down you can switch to Unity Registry and download it from there unless you're using a really old version

Answer (score 0):

Lots of missing functions are added to the 2020 version - you might want to update your unity to the newer one. You can check [the unity change log here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/changelog/CHANGELOG.html)

`OnCameraSetup` is added in 2020

Comment: You can also include the solution that can be found at your link in your answer, as the link might change or go offline.